# How to calculate this Zariski cotangent space explicitly?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$\newcommand{\mp}{\mathfrak{m}_p}$Let $\mathcal{C}=\{ (x,y): x^2+y^2-1=0 \} \subset \mathbb{C}^2$, let $p \in (a,b)$, and let $$\mathfrak{m}_p = \langle x-a,y-b\rangle/\langle x^2 + y^2 -1\rangle. $$ The problem is to show that $\mp/\mp^2$ is a 1-dimensional [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_tangent_space) over $\mathbb{C}$, of the form (I believe) $\{ (ta,tb): t\in \mathbb{C} \}$ (because I am supposed to relate $\mp/\mp^2$ with the span of $\nabla(x^2+y^2-1)(p)$, since they are both supposed to be alternative ways of describing the cotangent space at $p$).

I have already shown that $$x^2+y^2-1 = (x+a)(x-a)+(y+b)(y-b) $$ because $p\in (a,b) \implies a^2 + b^2 -1=0,$ and I have also already shown ([see p.2 here](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/gfarkas/teaching/alggeom/march4.pdf)) that: $$\mp/\mp^2 = \{ f_1(a,b)(x-a) + f_2(a,b)(y-b): f_1, f_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]/\langle x^2 + y^2 -1 \rangle  \} $$ However, this is not of the form I want, and thus not one-dimensional (I think), unless $f_1(a,b)=f_2(a,b)$, and I am completely at a loss for how to show this.

**Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?**

This is Exercise 4.14.8, p. 238 of *[Algebraic-Geometry: A Problem-Solving Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821893963)* by Garrity et al. This isn't homework, I'm just stuck on this problem, which is the second-to-last problem of the section, and I want to move on to the next section.

**EDIT:** The calculation done [here](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=41163) says that the dimension of $\mp/\mp^2$ for an analogous hypersurface is two-dimensional -- in fact, if one replaces $\bar{x}$ with $x-a$ and $\bar{y}$ with $y-b$ everywhere, it looks almost exactly the same as my work calculating $\mp/\mp^2$, except that at the end the author is able to conclude that $\mp/\mp^2 \simeq (k \cdot \bar{x} \oplus k \cdot \bar{y} \oplus \langle \bar{x}^2, \bar{x}\bar{y}, \bar{y}^2 \rangle)/\langle \bar{x}^2, \bar{x}\bar{y}, \bar{y}^2 \rangle \simeq k\cdot x \oplus k \cdot y$ which is supposed to be two-dimensional. In contrast, the authors of my book (4.15.3 on p.240) state that the dimension of any irreducible smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is $n-1$, and that the dimension of the tangent space (and thus of the cotangent space) agrees with the dimension at all smooth points. And $x^2 + y^2 -1$ is a non-degenerate conic section, hence smooth. Is the hypersurface defined by [$xy - x^6 - y^6$](http://www.sosmath.com/CBB/viewtopic.php?t=41163) singular at $(0,0)$? Otherwise I have no idea how to explain the discrepancy.

The formula at the bottom of the [first page here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~bertram/6030/Nonsingular.pdf) is almost certainly relevant -- I am still figuring out how to apply it in this instance.

Comment: Can you show that the vector space in question is generated by $x-a, y-b$ first? Then using your equation (writing $x^2+y^2-1$ as a linear combination of $x-a, y-b$) can you show $x-a, y-b$ are linearly dependent modulo square of the maximal ideal?

Comment: @Mohan Do you mean I can use the fact that $(x-a)(y-b)\sim ab, (x-a)^2 \sim a^2, (y-b)^2 \sim b^2$ to show that $x-a, y-b$ are linearly dependent? Then $$\frac{y-b}{x-a}=\frac{(x-a)(y-b)}{(x-a)^2}=\frac{ab}{a^2}=\frac{b}{a}, $$ so I can claim that $(y-b) = \frac{b}{a}(x-a)$? Is that legal?

Comment: @Mohan Or modulo square of the maximal ideal $$(x+a)(x-a)+(y+b)(y-b)=x^2+y^2-1 \sim a^2 +b^2 - 1 = 0  $$ so $x-a,y-b$ are linearly dependent using polynomial coefficients, but don't I need to show that they are linearly dependent using coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$? Although I guess that criterion could only make them linearly independent when $(x+a)=0, (y+b)=0$, i.e. $x=-a, y=-b$, although I'm still not sure where that gets me. I tried reducing the equation further, and got $$-1=a(x-a)+b(y-b)$$ but obviously because the left hand side is non-zero I still feel like am stuck.

Comment: @Mohan At the point $(a,b)$, $$x+a=2a=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^2+y^2-1)\mid_{(a,b)}, \\ y+b=2b=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(x^2 + y^2 -1)\mid_{(a,b)}$$ so setting that into $0=(x+a)(x-a)+(y+b)(y-a)$ we get $$0=2a(x-a)+2b(x-b)$$ which seems essentially like what I want, gives a 1D vector space, is clearly related to the gradient of $x^2+y^2-1$, and matches up with the formula for $\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ given here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~bertram/6030/Nonsingular.pdf . However, why can set $x=a,y=b$ into $x+a,y+b$, but simultaneously _not_ into $x-a, y-b$? I don't get that.

Comment: @William: because $x-a$ and $y-b$ are generating $\mathfrak m_p$ over $A:= \mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2 + y^2 - 1)$, and now $\mathfrak m_p/\mathfrak m_p^2$ is an $A$-module which is annihilated by $\mathfrak m_p$, so that on this module $\mathfrak m_p$ acts by zero, hence $x$ acts by $a$ and $y$ by $b$.  But you don't get to apply this to the *generators* of the module, only to the elements of $A$ when you make them *act* on the module.  It's the same reason that if you look at the quotient $2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, it is annihilated by $2$, but you don't get to say "oh, $2 = 0$ on this module, and ...

Comment: its generator is $2$, so this module actually vanishes''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that you have shown that $(x+a) (x-a) + (x+b)(x-b) = x^2 + y^2 - 1.$ This mean, when you work modulo the $x^2+y^2  - 1$, you have shown that $(x+a)(x-a)  + (x+b)(x-b) \equiv 0.$  But $\mathfrak m_p/\mathfrak m_p^2$ is annihilated by $\mathfrak m_p,$ so that on this quotient $x$ and $y$ both acts as scalars.

So, as Mohan wrote in comments, you have found a linear dependence between $(x-a)$ and $(y-b)$, and so you're done.

This is just a form of the implicit, or maybe inverse, function theorem.  If $p = (a,b)$ is a smooth point of $f = 0$, then the formula $df_{|(a,b)} = 0$ will always yield a non-trivial linear dependence relation between $x-a$ and $y-b$ in $\mathfrak m_p/\mathfrak m_p^2$.

Comment: When you say "$\mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2$ is annihilated by $\mathfrak{m_p}$, so that on this quotient x and y both act as scalars", what does that mean? I get that it means that I am already done, but not much else. You also write earlier that "x acts by a and y acts by b", which I kind of get, but I thought only $x^2$ acts by $a^2$, $y^2$ acts by $b^2$, and $xy$ acts by $ab$, but otherwise we can't say anything about the linear terms? This is obviously wrong but I'm not sure why; I thought only higher order terms could be reduced to expressions involving $a,b$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure how to show that $x+a \equiv_{\mp^2} 2a$ or that $y+b \equiv_{\mp^2} 2b$, and I will add that later if I figure it out, but I finally understand why $x-a$ and $y-b$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{C}$ (mod $\mp^2$):

$$0 \equiv_{\langle x^2 + y^2 -1 \rangle} x^2(x^2 + y^2 -1) = x^2(x+a)(x-a)+x^2(y+b)(y-b)\equiv_{\mp^2} 2a^3(x-a)+2a^2b(y-b) $$ when $a\not=0$ works, and if $a=0$ then $y \not=0$, because $-1\not=0 \implies (0,0)\not\in\{(x,y):x^2 + y^2 -1 =0 \}$ so we can use instead: $$0 \equiv_{\langle x^2 + y^2 -1 \rangle} y^2(x^2 + y^2 -1) = y^2(x+a)(x-a)+y^2(y+b)(y-b)\equiv_{\mp^2} 2b^2a(x-a)+2b^3(y-b) $$ although if either $a=0$ or $b=0$ then one of the coefficients in this expression is still $0$ -- however, if $a=0$, then $x-a=x+a=x$, so we have that $(x+a)(x-a)=x^2 \equiv_{\mp^2} 0$, likewise if $b=0$ then $(y-b)(y+b)=y^2 \equiv_{\mp^2} 0$, i.e. either $x$ respectively $y$ is nilpotent, so we get $$0 \equiv_{\langle x^2 +y^2 -1 \rangle} y^2(x)(x)+y^2(y+b)(y-b) \quad with\ y^2x \equiv_{\mp^2} b^2x \not=0,\ y^2(y+b)\equiv_{\mp^2} 2b^3 \not=0 $$ $$0 \equiv_{\langle x^2 +y^2 -1 \rangle} x^2(x+a)(x-a)+x^2(y)(y) \quad with\ x^2(x+a) \equiv_{\mp^2} 2a^3 \not=0,\ x^2(y)\equiv_{\mp^2} a^2y \not=0 $$ and thus linear dependence still holds.

At least when $a\not=0\not=b$, we have as a result that $$0 \equiv_{\langle x^2 +y^2 -1 \rangle, \mp^2} 2a(x-a)+2b(y-b) $$ (i.e. divide by $a^2 \not=0$ or by $b^2\not=0$), which obviously has the same form as the tangent space $$\{(x,y): \nabla f\cdot ((x,y)-(a,b))=0  \}=\{(x,y): 2a(x-a)+2b(y-b)=0 \} $$ which is an even stronger resemblance than I had hoped to show originally.